# How do I change the name of an application tab?

Tags: facebook

I'm working on a facebook page for a client and with the new profiles pages starting to roll out I've come across an issue with the name of the app I created. The original profiles which most of you will see here - http://www.facebook.com/DrMartyBecker says "Welcome" as the tab name. On the new profile pages the tab says 'drMARTY', I can't find the place where I can modify the name. So i was wondering if there was a way to change this and where. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

piece of cake:

1. Go to: http://www.facebook.com/developers/
2. Select your application and click "more"
3. Select Edit Settings
4. On left side menu, choose Facebook Integration
5. The fourth configuration block is respective to Tab settings
6. Change "Tab Name"
7. Click on "Save Changes" button

Your Tab was renamed!

[]'s,

And Past